# How to add git submodule using SSH and entering the passphrase in one line?

Tags: git, ssh, command-line

I'm building a macOS app that needs to have the ability to add a submodule to a repository.

This is the command I'm using

```
git submodule add -b develop git@bitbucket.org:account/repo.git dependencies/myDependency
```

The problem is that after I run that command, I get the typical "Enter passphrase for key..." message.
Since I'm doing this programmatically it will be much more convenient if I could skip that second step.

So, that's my question, can I modify this url *"git@bitbucket.org:account/repo.git"* in a certain way that it already contains the SSH password, or is there any other git parameter I could add?

I don't want to use HTTPS, and I also wouldn't like to force the user to configure their SSH settings on a specific way.

Comment: There is no ssh password if they are using an SSH key (which they should with the SSH way).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - I'm referring to the [passphrase](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/passphrase).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, there are tools to do so, for instance have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/362280/enter-ssh-passphrase-once

For MacOS: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/

And on Windows, you have to load the key in a manager, so it has to be handled by the key manager.

Comment: Like I said in the question, unfortunately, telling the user how to modify their SSH settings is not an option for me.

Comment: But that's the proper way to do things. They need to configure things. Git won't do it on its own. It's meant for users that would know that they need to configure their system. And in a way, it's just one additional step on the key configuration anyway.